# Schedule of cricket matches sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with list of countries as shown below. Every country will play against all countries in the list. I need a query to display the list of opponent countries in format (country1, country2) for all the possible matches without repetitions. e.g. c1 & c2 will play against each other. Display list should not have c2 & c1 (repetition)

```
CtryName
---
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
```

It's an interview question. I have no idea how to get expected results. Please help me by a simple query to display expected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select t1.c teamA, t2.c teamB
  from test t1,
       test t2
 where t1.c < t2.c
order by t1.c, t2.c
```

I named the table as `test` and the country column as `c`.

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9124f/2

Comment: Thanks Jorge, It's works perfectly. But i din't get how lees than '<' symbol compares strings

Comment: It simple compares with the alphabetical order `c1` string is lesser than `c2` string...